# ORACLE - Insert query running longer than usual - Table locks found - Lock mode 3

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

I am currently running into an issue, where in our INSERT is running longer than usual time. I have checked the details but, did not find any issues on wait-events but, I only see one thing Lock mode 3 for the table. Need help on how can I proceed with troubleshooting.

```
SID    SERIAL# USERNAME        OSUSER          MACHINE         EVENT                                    STATE               WAIT_CLASS
---------- ---------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------------------------------- ------------------- ---------------
      1165       5998 DCT             ims             mymac544        cell single block physical read          WAITED SHORT TIME   User I/O

SQL> select sid,serial#,username,status,osuser,machine,program,sql_id,blocking_session from gv$session where sid=1165;

       SID    SERIAL# USERNAME        STATUS   OSUSER          MACHINE         PROGRAM                   SQL_ID        BLOCKING_SESSION
---------- ---------- --------------- -------- --------------- --------------- ------------------------- ------------- ----------------
      1165       5998 DCT             ACTIVE   ims             mymac544        sqlplus@mymac544 (TNS V1- 0jgpjjb4nq9yz
                                                                               V3)

SELECT XIDUSN,xidslot,xidsqn,object_id,SESSION_ID,ORACLE_USERNAME,OS_USER_NAME,PROCESS,locked_mode from v$locked_object;


    XIDUSN    XIDSLOT     XIDSQN  OBJECT_ID SESSION_ID ORACLE_USERNAME OS_USER_NAME    PROCESS                  LOCKED_MODE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------- --------------- ------------------------ -----------
       150         31    2130026    5424066       1165 DCT             ims             14171                              3
       150         31    2130026    5424067       1165 DCT             ims             14171                              3
       150         31    2130026    5424057       1165 DCT             ims             14171                              3
```

Thanks
Mohammeddba

Comment: Are there any unindexed foreign keys from/to this table?

Comment: is this an insert select ? or just simple ? is this table contains lot of data ? are there space in the database ?

Comment: Yes its an INSERT statement, it contains 5 lakh rows in it and yes there is lot of space in that associated tablesace.

Comment: Lock mode 3 is completely normal for an insert/update operation, that number represents a row exclusive lock that happens when table rows are updated. How much longer are inserts taking compared to normal? Have there been any recent changes to the table or database that occurred around the same time that the issue started? Things like a database upgrade can change performance and require tuning. Adding/removing indexes can also change things, there are many potential variables.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs, It worked when we collected the statistics for tables.